# Accessing kubernetres dashboard from Google web preview/ shell

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Using google Kubernetes engine:

```
kubectl cluster-info
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://x.x.x.x/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy
```

If I go to the link:

I get to a forbidden page and if I accepts I get the following:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kubernetes-dashboard\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace \"kube-system\": Unknown user \"system:anonymous\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Is it not possible to access the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That url points to the Kubernetes API that requires authentication, and it's not the place to access the dashboard via web.

If you want to access the kubernetes dashboard, there are different options

- Use [kubectl proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui) to access the dashboard on http://localhost:8001/ui.
- Use port-forwarding to access the Pod that's running the dashboard. Useful while developing.
- Expose the dashboard using a service of type `NodePort`. Then you can access the dashboard on `node_public_ip:NodePort`.
- Deploy an ingress controller and define an ingress rule that exposes the dashboard on a custom domain.

Answer (score 1):

This message says, you should login with valid authentication to the UI Dashboard it can be with token or cluster config. If you want to login using token, follow the steps below:

1. Get list of all secret tokens:

   kubectl -n kube-system get secret
2. Get the token:

   kubectl -n kube-system describe secret [NameOfToken]
3. Run Proxy:

   kubectl proxy
4. Enter the dashboard link:

   http://localhost:8001/ui
5. Copy the token and order it in one line and put it on dashboard UI